# Trouble implementing quicksort recursion in java

Tags: java

I'm doing a project for school and I have to test the speeds of binary vs linear searches for a spellcheck implementation. We have to use this certain SpellCheck. The examples given by my professor for `binary` search using recursion were a few separate snippets of code designed for ints and he wants us to make it work for this implementation with strings. Any help would be appreciated, I am very stuck at the moment. `SortedWordList` is the class i need help on.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;


public class Spellcheck {

    private static WordList listOfWords;// The list of correctly spelled words.


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        listOfWords = new SortedWordList();
        //listOfWords = new WordList();
        long end = System.nanoTime(); 
        long WL = (end-start);
        //end = 0;
        //start = 0;
        long SW = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {  // Get and process one word from the user.
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter a word to be cheched (press return to end):  ");
            String word = in.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
            start = System.nanoTime();
            if (word.length() == 0)
                break;
            if (listOfWords.contains(word)) {
                System.out.println("'" + word + "' is a legal word.");

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("'" + word + "' is not a legal word.");
                System.out.println("If there are similar words, they are shown here:");
                trySubstitute(word);
                tryInsert(word);
                tryDelete(word);
                trySwap(word);
                tryBreak(word);
                end = System.nanoTime();
                SW = (end-start);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("Time to create word list: %,d nanoseconds.%n",(WL));
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("Time to test for similar words: %,d nanoseconds.%n",(SW));
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("Time to test total: %,d nanoseconds.%n",(SW + WL));
        }

    }

    private static void trySubstitute(String word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            String before = word.substring(0, i);
            String after = word.substring(i+1);
            for (char ch = 'a'; ch < 'z'; ch++) {
                String newword = before + ch + after;
                if (listOfWords.contains(newword))
                    System.out.println("   " + newword);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void tryInsert(String word) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++) {
            String before = word.substring(0,i);
            String after = word.substring(i);
            for (char ch = 'a'; ch < 'z'; ch++) {
                String newword = before + ch + after;
                if (listOfWords.contains(newword))
                    System.out.println("   " + newword);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void tryDelete(String word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            String before = word.substring(0, i);
            String after = word.substring(i+1);
            String newword = before + after;
            if (listOfWords.contains(newword))
                System.out.println("   " + newword);
        }
    }


    private static void trySwap(String word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
            String before = word.substring(0, i);
            char a = word.charAt(i);
            char b = word.charAt(i+1);
            String after = word.substring(i+2);
            String newword = before + b + a + after;
            if (listOfWords.contains(newword)) 
                System.out.println("   " + newword);

        }
    }

    private static void tryBreak(String word) {
        for (int i = 1; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
            String before = word.substring(0, i);
            String after = word.substring(i);
            if (listOfWords.contains(before) && listOfWords.contains(after))
                System.out.println("   " + before + " " + after);
        }       
    }

} // end class Spellcheck
`

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.URL;


public class WordList {

   protected final String[] words;  // the list of words

   public WordList() {
      try {
         URL listLocation = WordList.class.getClassLoader().getResource("unsorted_words.txt");
         Scanner in = new Scanner( listLocation.openStream() );
         ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
         while (in.hasNextLine())
            wordList.add(in.nextLine());
         words = wordList.toArray(new String[] {});
         in.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Can't load list of words from file 'unsorted_words.txt'");
      }
   }

   public boolean contains(String lowerCaseWord) {
      for (String s : words) {
         if (s.equals(lowerCaseWord))
            return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   public int size() {
      return words.length;
   }

   public String get(int index) {
      return words[index];
   }


}

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortedWordList extends WordList {


    public String [] words;


    public SortedWordList() { 
        URL listLocation = SortedWordList.class.getClassLoader().getResource("unsorted_words.txt");
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner( listLocation.openStream() );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (in.hasNextLine())
           wordList.add(in.nextLine());
        words = wordList.toArray(new String[] {});
        in.close();
    }

        //public boolean contains(String lowerCaseWord) {

       //}


    static int binarySearch(String[] A, int loIndex, int hiIndex, String value) {

       if (loIndex > hiIndex) {

          return -1;
       }

       else {

          int middle = (loIndex + hiIndex) / 2;
          if (value == A[middle])
             return middle;
          else if ((A[middle].compareTo(value)) > 0)
             return binarySearch(A, loIndex, middle - 1, value);
          else   // value must be > A[middle]
             return binarySearch(A, middle + 1, hiIndex, value);
       }

    } // end binarySearch()




     static int quicksortStep(String[] A, int lo, int hi) {

        String pivot = A[lo];  // Get the pivot value.



        while (hi > lo) {

           while (hi > lo && ((pivot.compareTo(A[hi])) <= 0)) {

              hi--;
           }

           if (hi == lo)
              break;

           A[lo] = A[hi];
           lo++;

           while (hi > lo && ((pivot.compareTo(A[lo])) >= 0)) {

              lo++;
           }

           if (hi == lo)
              break;

           A[hi] = A[lo];
           hi--;

        } // end while

        A[lo] = pivot;
        return lo;

     }  // end QuicksortStep


     static void quicksort(String[] A, int lo, int hi) {

            if (hi <= lo) {

               return;
            }
            else {

               int pivotPosition = quicksortStep(A, lo, hi);
               quicksort(A, lo, pivotPosition - 1);
               quicksort(A, pivotPosition + 1, hi);
            }
         }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, where do you need to call quicksort? Just guessing by the class's name of SortedWordList, it would seem to me that you would need to call this quicksort method inside the SortedWordList's constructor. Right now, the constructor appears to load an unsorted list of words.

If that doesn't solve the problem, I would then also look at your quicksortStep method inside the SortedWordList class again. This quicksortStep method is basically the partition method. (See https://www.programcreek.com/2012/11/quicksort-array-in-java/ for an example). I would try to follow the same code structure in the quicksortStep method as the partition method in the link above, and then modify it for strings, until it is something like:

```
public static int partition(String[] arr, int start, int end){
    String pivot = arr[end];

    for(int i=start; i<end; i++){
        if((arr[i].compareTo(pivot)) < 0){
            String temp= arr[start];
            arr[start]=arr[i];
            arr[i]=temp;
            start++;
        }
    }

    String temp = arr[start];
    arr[start] = pivot;
    arr[end] = temp;

    return start;
}
```

Feel free to rename methods / variables.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have been trying to call the quicksort method I made in the sortedWordList constructor, however my string [] 'words' is not static and will not accept being used with my static quicksort() method. While running it now, I get improved timing over the linear method however i think the initial spellcheck is using binary however the .contains to suggest new words are using the super's .contains

Comment: Do those methods inside SortedWordList need to be static?